# Hbase installation failure

Tags: installation, hadoop

I am trying to start hbase with the following command:

> hadoop@user-HP-dx2480-MT-NA125PA:/usr/local/hadoop/hbase$
>   bin/start-hbase.sh

and the startup fails with the following errror:

> error are localhost: starting
>   zookeeper, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-hadoop-zookeeper-user-HP-dx2480-MT-NA125PA.out
>   localhost: java.net.BindException:
>   Address already in use localhost:     at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
>   localhost:    at
>   sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:137)
>   localhost:    at
>   sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:77)
>   localhost:    at
>   sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:70)
>   localhost:    at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn$Factory.(NIOServerCnxn.java:122)
>   localhost:    at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:106)
>   localhost:    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.runZKServer(HQuorumPeer.java:85)
>   localhost:    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.main(HQuorumPeer.java:70)

What is the solution for this? Can anyone tel me? What is AddressBindingException??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your zookeeper process is already running.  Or (much less likely), something else is already listening on port 2181 or 2888.  Did you install a separate zookeeper package and start it?

If so, you'll need to tell HBase not to start zookeeper automatically.  Edit the conf/hbase-env.sh file and add the line:

```
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
```

On the other hand, if you want HBase to start zookeeper automatically, then change that setting to "true", make sure any current zookeeper process is stopped and try again.

FYI, if you run into more problems, subscribe to the HBase user mailing list at user-subscribe@hbase.apache.org and we can help you further there.